# How to launch SQL Server Agent job on completion of another one?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, maintenance, sql-server-agent

An SQL Server Agent job (SSA) have to be executed after a few other SSA jobs.

Is there any way to start SSA jobs on completion (or success, or failure) of another one?

Currently, I do this on schedule adding the delay for the duration of previous jobs. This is uncomfortable for many reasons:

- the real execution time of preceding job can exceed the usual time and and the follow-up job will start without required completion;
- if to include the follow-up processing as job steps then I need to duplicate them over a few jobs

SQL Server 2012 R2 on Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [sp_start_job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx).

Put that command into a job step as needed. No need to worry about the duration of previous jobs.

Comment: But, this is what I mentioned in "if to include the follow-up processing as job steps then I need to duplicate them over a few jobs". For example, I need to copy local backups created by 2 SQL Server Agent job (running the weekly and daily maintenance plans, resp.). Then I need to create the same follow-up steps (which are quite big and numerous) and I need to synchronize the possible changes in the dupes not only inside the different jobs of the same server but, also, between **dozens** different regional servers!

Comment: What @SQLRockstar meant was that you create a job with all your follow-up steps and add a new step in your existing jobs using `sp_start_job` to start it.

Comment: @Fulproof You could choose to look at creating master jobs, too. Also, jobs can be scripted, so if you had to make a change to many servers you could get that done using a script, too.